# Make a wire thicker will work to avoid overheat?

Tags: power, wire, cables, heat, insulation

I'm new to this community and it's a pleasure to start rolling in it! I have a simple question in regards to wire overheat that I hope you guys help me to solve, any help is deeply appreciated =)

I have a Forza FVR-1200va power regulator that I use to supply my PC along with some other small accesories, if I have many things working at the same time and I use, let's say, a very cheap and thin extension cord, this starts heating immediately, if I don't turn the regulator off or disconnect the cord from the main outlet the cable is pretty much condemned to melt, I understand that, but, I've been wondering... Given that thicker cords have zero cons against this type of situations, what would happen if I manage to make thicker the first cord somehow? for example, if I remove the insulating plastic and get to the copper of a large segment of the wires (not including the outers that go soldered/attached to the metal connectors) then use some extra copper wires from other cables to double the size, twist everything, and carefully reinsulate the cutted segments with heat shrinking tube or any other material, would that be enough to avoid the overheating? I'm not planning to do any of this by the way, I'm just curious =) would that work at all?

Comment: That sounds incredibly dangerous. Why would you not simply buy a properly sized extension cord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you do to reduce the resistance, or increase the copper cross-section, in the circuit will reduce the heat generated.  Just running multiple conductors in parallel (no need to strip the insulation except at the ends, for termination) will reduce the current, and therefore heat generation, in each conductor.

However, the preferred solution is to use an appropriate sized cable in the first place.